# C++ initialization of local/global object

Tags: c++

I've already encountered many time the case when there's a class, e.g. `LogFile`, that has no default constructor, while I want to initialize an instance of it, not on the heap.

Here is an example:

```
LogFile logfile;

void init(const std::string& path) {
    logfile = LogFile(path);
}
```

The above code will not compile, since `LogFile` class has no default constructor.

There are a few workarounds I currently use:

1.
Persisting not to make any heap calls manually, storing the object in a list (the list will for sure use the heap, but I won't care about it)

```
std::list<LogFile> logfile_holder;

void init(const std::string& path) {
    logfile_holder.push_back(LogFile(path));
}
```

2.
Using the heap, with a shared pointer/unique pointer:

```
std::shared_ptr<LogFile> logfile_ptr;

void init(const std::string& path) {
    logfile_ptr.reset(new LogFile(path));
}
```

I there a more standard solution for doing such things?

Even something that looks like the list workaround, but with a template class that is designated specifically for this purpose, without the overhead of the list, would be nice.

Comment: why not simply `Logfile logfile = createLogFile(/*...*/);`?

Comment: I need it to be initialized later. The `init()` function should  be called from somewhere else

Comment: @tobi303 Most probably because the logfile path isn't known at compile time.

Comment: @Chur7U I'd stick with the `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @user0042 it doesnt need the logfile path at compile time, just when the prgoram starts.

Comment: Might be a cleaner design to not expose `LogFile` as a global at all, and pass it in to functions which need it. So after you've created it, you can pass it as an argument, by reference/pointer to whomever needs it. If too many things need it, then perhaps add a `get` method next to that `init` one.

Comment: @tobi303 many times applications start with parsing the configurations and only then they call the init functions. There's nowhere to get the path of the log file before the parsing of the configuration. The init should be done later

Comment: Can `logfile` not just be a local variable in `main`?

Comment: @BaummitAugen Then it can't be accessed from everywhere.

Comment: A possible complete solution would be to separate the logger and the logfile, then have a global logger that defaults to `stderr` or something and then open and set the desired logfile in `main`. This has the nice added benefit that you can already log stuff like "failure to open logfile".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use indirection. Use a global pointer, and initialize it with a function local static:

```
LogFile* logfile_ptr;

void init(const std::string& path) {
    static LogFile logfile(path);
    logfile_ptr = &logfile;
}
```

---

For your suggestions, there is little point in using a list (or other data structure) when you could use a smart pointer if you were to use heap.

Do note that in this design based on yours, you need to pay attention to not use the global logfile until it has been initialized. If unsure, it is easy to check if the pointer is null.

A simpler approach would be to simply add the default constructor. That would allow changing the behaviour of `Logfile` if it is used before the path is set. For example, you could terminate the program and describe the error, or you could silently ignore such bugs if you don't care about premature logging that goes missing. Or you could even store logging into a buffer and flush it as soon as the path is finally initialized.

Comment: Wow, it looks amazing! just a little comment - the init of the static variable should call the constructor with the path

Comment: @Chur7U indeed :)

Comment: Leave a comment so to remember not to delete the indirected pointer :S

Comment: @Chur7U Meh, `init` routines are hardly "amazing". They are the least bad solution at best usually.

Comment: @Griffin there should be no feeling of urge to delete a pointer unless you have called `new`.

Comment: @user2079303 True if 5 lines of code. False if working with a bigger source code. Comments never hurt.

Comment: @Griffin I don't think it has much to do with size, but with quality of design (although size probably exacerbates bad design). If you find yourself calling `delete` on a pointer whose source is unknown, then something has gone horribly wrong.

Comment: @user2079303 The reason of not being confident with code is that it is relying on programmer's judgment rather than limiting the chance of fault. In my hypothetical mind nothing stops me form pass that pointer to another component and nothing stops that component from deleting it. A good code would eliminate the concern by design as much as possible.

Comment: @Griffin nothing stops a component from deleting non-pointer objects either by taking their address. Comments are sometimes needed, but it is important to not drown the entire code base in them. I reserve them for cases that are counter intuitive and need explanation. A Global pointer needs no explanation. You just don't delete them unless you also assign them; there is no judgment call. Now, a function returning a pointer would certainly need a comment that describes whether the function allocates memory and how to dispose of it.

Comment: One improvement suggestion: let `init()`just return a reference instead of void, then the caller is free to use it in which way he wants and you do not need to directly reference a global variable from within `init()`.

Comment: @ user2079303 Sorry for writing too early, had to correct my comment. Returning the (static local) object via reference (or pointer) is still cleaner, I think. You avoid enforcing a global variable. The the user wants to do that, he still can do - but he is not forced to do so.

Comment: @KingThrushbeard but then any code that wants that static log file, would need to pass the path argument, even though only the first one actually initializes the object. That would be highly confusing, and bad design in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

`optional` can be an alternative (`std` or `boost` one depending of your version of compiler):

```
std::optional<LogFile> logfile;

void init(const std::string& path) {
    logfile = LogFile(path);
}
```

Comment: Was it introduced in C++14 (in `std`)?

Comment: [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) is available since C++17.

Comment: Since I don't use boost (and so a lot of other developers), and since C++17 is not yet very popular, I preferred this time @user207930's answer. I think that along years, when C++17 becomes as common as C++11 is nowadays, your answer would be the winner

Comment: Programatically, it is exactly the solution I wanted to have

Comment: You may still *implement* your own `optional`.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is to separate a `Logger` class and have a `Logfile` class which are coupled internally and separate responsibilities:

- The `Logger` class is instantiated when needed and is used to write text formatted logging messages
- The `Logfile` class is responsible for the configuration of the application wide logfile. There will be a `static` class member representing the `std::ostream` shared with all the `Logger` instances.

Here's a sketch:

```
class Logfile {
    friend class Logger;
    static std::unique_ptr<std::ostream> plogstream_;

public:
    void set_logfile(const std::string& logfile_path) {
    void set_logstream(std::unique_ptr<std::ostream> logstream);
};

Logfile::plogstream_ = std::unique_ptr<std::ostream>(std::cerr,[](void*){});

class Logger {
public:
     operator ostream&()() {
          return *Logfile::plogstream_;
     }
};
```